# Android error "Selection does not contain a main type"

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

So I was working on this Bluetooth project on Android and when I tried to run it (on an android device, of course) it gave me this error message

> selection does not contain a main type

A solution is to add the main class

> public static void main (String[] arg)

I never had to do that before. Why am I getting that error now? And how do I successfully add public static void main (String[] arg), and where?
I looked through an old project's files to look for that line but couldn't find it, and the project runs perfectly.

I am still a beginner with Bluetooth.

Comment: Double check that you have an *Android* project, not a *Java* project, in Eclipse.

Comment: Also describe the steps that you take that gives that error, since it doesn't sound like one which is attached to a specific line of code

Comment: @code-guru Yes it is an Android project, not a java one. I have only tried to run it as an Android Application using a connected device. Same steps I follow every time for running other applications.

Comment: Just to clarify, let me restate my suggestion: Be sure that you created the project by going to File -> New -> Android Application Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is an android project, you don't need a main method.
You should have a class that extends an Activity and have that class added in your manifest.xml file.

Is your android device properly connected? Where do you see this error message?
Have you been able to launch any other demo application on your android device?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought and that is why I was confused with that answer, which a friend suggested! 
Yes I have tried launching other demo applications on the device and they all worked. I'm going to make a new project, copy and paste my code and edit it, hopefully I don't get that error again. Thank you and I hope it doesn't bother you if I write back with more questions.

Comment: No problem. One more thing: I don't know which version of eclipse you use, but I used to work with a vesion downloaded from the eclipse website on which I added the android plugin manually. I somethime had problems when creating new projects. I downloaded a new version of eclipse from the android website (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) which contains everything needed and I haven't had any trouble launching an android project since. Good luck for your project

Comment: I have Eclipse Kepler with the android plugin so that might be it. I will surely accept the answer! :)